# What object am I referring to in this sentence?

Tags: nouns, ambiguity, objects, reference, anaphora

I apologize if my question is too basic, my English is a little rusty and I have always had trouble with this concept:

Consider the following sentence:

> Once I finished the project, I found that generating a beautiful image with a ray-tracer is a lot more challenging than actually implementing one.

When I say "implementing one", am I referring to "a beautiful image" or to "a ray-tracer". I would like to refer to "a ray-tracer", but I am unsure about which one is being addressed here.

Comment: "with a ray-tracer" is a prepositional phrase here, and "a beautiful image" is the object of the verb "generating". So for parallel structure, "implementing " would appear to refer to "a beautiful image". But I could be wrong. I think possibly your sentence could be worded better for clarity.

Comment: Since you are unsure, you can bet the reader will be unsure, too.  Clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native speaker, my first interpretation is that *one* refers to *beautiful image*.  It was only the disconnect between "implenting" and "image" that made me stop and reconsider.

The reason is that you're saying that *generating* is harder than *implementing* so the assumption is that you're doing those two actions to the same object -- in this case, the image.  (How you generated the image -- i.e., with a ray-tracer -- is irrelevant to the parallelism of the sentence structure.)

If you want to avoid this ambiguity, you could say:

> Once I finished the project, I found that ***using a ray-tracer to generate*** a beautiful image is a lot more challenging than actually implementing one.

or even:

> Once I finished the project, I found that ***using a ray-tracer*** is a lot more challenging than actually implementing one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But if the user is generating a beautiful image, surely it is a result of  implementing that tool? No? I don't get it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- When confused, I drop out the unnecessary bits and see what I'm left with.  In _I found that generating a beautiful image with a ray-tracer is a lot more challenging than actually implementing one._, the _with a ray-tracer_ provides more info about generating the image, but it's not strictly necessary [1] so let's take that out and see what we have: _... generating a beautiful image is a lot more challenging than actually implementing one._  So what does _one_ stand for?  the only thing left -- a beautiful image.

Comment: [1] if you want to say that _with a ray-tracer_ **is** critical, then the sentence becomes _I found that generating (a beautiful image with a ray-tracer) is a lot more challenging than actually implementing (a beautiful image with a ray-tracer).

Comment: No sorry, perhaps I haven't made myself clear. I am asking about generating and implementing. Not if "implement" refers to "image". So, if one *generates* an image, how can the OP say he finds it easier to generate an image rather than implementing the ray tracer?  P.S I have no idea what a "ray tracer" is, it sounds like something from Star Trek, but I gather it must be graphic designer tool or software program(me). Generating an image with a "ray tracer"  is more challenging than Implementing (using)  a "ray tracer". This is the bit I don't understand.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- I'm no expert, but I believe that in this context, _generating_ is similar to _drawing_ and _implementing_ probably means either _writing_/_creating_ or perhaps _installing_.  I suspect that the OP is a programmer who wrote a ray-tracer (used in computer animation, I believe) program and then tried to draw something with it.  That's why I mentioned the disconnect between _implementing_ and _image_.  If you ignore the meaning, the word _one_ refers to _image_, but then (if you add the meaning back in) it makes no sense.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- it's as if I said "_I sat down at the table and ate it._" Perhaps I meant I ate the meal I'd previously prepared, but that's not what the sentence says.

Comment: Another note -- In the sentence "_I sat down at the table and ate it_", the pronoun _it_ refers to the previous noun -- the table.  But because that makes no sense (we don't usually eat tables), the listener would look for some other noun that _would_ make sense.  (Perhaps I had actually said "_I made some delicious pasta.  I sat down at the table and ate it._" in which case, a rational person would assume I ate the pasta.)  In your example, however, because a lot of people don't know what a ray-tracer is or, really, what you're talking about at all, they would likely get lost in there.

Comment: As Roger accurately guessed, I am a software engineer. In my field, when a person writes a program (such as a ray-tracer), it is common to say things like "I _built_ a ray-tracer" or "I _implemented_ a ray-tracer". I understand those words are not necessarily the most appropriate, but they are the ones normally used when talking informally. I loved the 2nd option Roger provided in his response. When I finished writing my program (which took many months), I found it was very challenging to use it to generate pretty images because I am not an artist. Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: @DiMarzeloBellafonte The use of "implemented" is perfectly fine. It's the construction of the sentence. It confused even me (I'm a software developer and manager of 30 years) and I now see where the problem occurred. I will probably remove my answer as a result. Roger gave good options. Also it could be: "Once I finished the project I found that creating a beautiful image is much harder than actually implementing a/the ray-tracer."

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yep, as I said above (and down below) I have to agree. The usage of "implemented a beautiful image" was the confusing element. I need to update my answer or delete it. Your sentence construction made it appear as though you were talking about implementing a ray-tracer. Basically the noun and verb objects got completely garbled unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

The "one" refers to "a beautiful image" for the reason stated above - "with a ray tracer" adds information in a prepositional phrase, and is neither an object or subject here. But it still adds information about the image, so the sentence could be understood this way ...

"I found that generating a beautiful image with a ray-tracer is a lot more challenging than actually implementing (a beautiful image with a ray-tracer)."

The difficulty with this sentence for me is the use of the words "implement" and "generate". I'm not sure what a "ray-tracer" is, but I understand the concept of "generating an image with a ray-tracer", I'm just not sure what you are trying to "implement".

It sounds to me that you can 1. Generate images and then 2. Implement those images and that you are saying that it is easier to 1. Generate an image with a ray-tracer but that 2. an image generated with a ray-tracer is not as easy to implement (use) as it is to generate.

That is how I would read the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr* The object you're referring to is the *ray-tracer*.

---

You're asking about this sentence:

> Once I finished the project, I found that generating a beautiful image with a ray-tracer is a lot more challenging than actually implementing one.

There are (at least) a couple of ways to parse this.

The most straightforward approach is to consider *generating* and *implementing* to be parallel terms, making *implementing* refer to the *beautiful image*:

- generating (a beautiful image) ... is more challenging than ... implementing one

However, beautiful images aren't usually described in English as being *implemented*. They might be generated, drawn, etc, but [*implementation*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/implementation) doesn't fit - it makes the image sound as if it's a procedure. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=implement%20an%20image%2Cgenerate%20an%20image&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimplement%20an%20image%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgenerate%20an%20image%3B%2Cc0) shows that "implement an image" is much rarer than "generate an image". Clicking through to the underlying documents indicates that even on those rare occasions, it's the *image crop*, *image map* or *image viewer* that's being implemented, not the *image* itself.

Since *implementing* is such a poor fit with *image*, it would be more natural to parse the sentence the following way:

- (generating a beautiful image with) a ray-tracer is more challenging than ... implementing one

This essentially says that *doing something with X is harder than making X*. Replacing the second 'X' with a pronoun to better match your sentence, we can rephrase it to say **using X is harder than making it**.

Parsed this way, *implementing* is placed in parallel with *generating a beautiful image with*, and *one* refers to the *ray-tracer*.

This parsing to associate *one* with *ray-tracer* is natural because of the extremely weak association between *implementing* and *image*. However, if you wished to make it clearer, you might prefer to place *implementing* more directly in parallel with, say, *using*:

- Once I finished the project, I found that using a ray-tracer to generate a beautiful image is a lot more challenging than actually implementing one.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** *I will leave my answer here but please see Roger's post above. I think the intention is as Jim said in the bottom of the comments on this answer. Unfortunately I think what the OP wanted to say was:*

***"Once I finished the project, I found that creating a beautiful image is a lot more challenging than actually creating the ray-tracer."***

However, I will leave my answer because it might be beneficial for others who get confused or have the opposite meaning (as below)

---

Your usage is "not bad". I've modified it from my previous version of "perfect" because it does confuse some of the purists who are not familiar with ray-tracing. However, a native speaker would not confuse that you mean you are referring to the "ray-tracer" if you were in a tech environment.

**It's probably better served changing it as follows:**

> "Once I finished the project, I found that implementing a ray-tracer is a lot more challenging than generating a beautiful image."

My main reason for saying this was "perfect" (originally) was that regardless of the specific grammatically correct syntax, you cannot really "implement a beautiful image", and colloquially this sounded fine. Technically I suppose you could use those words ("implement a beautiful image"), but there is no computer scientist that I can imagine who would confuse your sentence as, "implementing a beautiful image" versus "implementing a ray-tracer".

The word *"implementing"* is highly idiomatic in software development and computer science and that is a major factor for why I didn't originally find fault with your sentence.

Personally I think your original version is fine, but to be absolutely grammatically correct you should probably go with the option I listed above.

*I made these edits after taking the comments section into consideration. Thank you all for your input.*

Comment: Once again please provide comments for down votes. I really think this site, and all sites like it, should require a comment for a down vote. It would at least give some inclination as to why the reader did not agree. Some down votes are totally acceptable but sometimes they just seem like people trolling, because this is ridiculous.

Comment: It’s likely due to your statement of “Your usage is perfect”  If it were perfect this question would not have come up at all.  The ambiguity exists and a slight reword could resolve it. So how is it perfect?

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/will-you-please-insist-on-explanations-for-down-voting

Comment: So you're not confused by the expression "implementing one" as used by the OP? You think everything he has said is perfect? Oh, no wait. The sentence is confusing because you cannot "implement a beautiful image" But that's exactly how I interpreted the sentence. By the way, how would you have phrased the original sentence?

Comment: @Jim First I'll address this one. Jim I said that because just the fact that he (or anyone for that matter) asked the question does not make it incorrect. He may be unclear on whether it's "perfect' (correct) or not and just wants some reinforcement on if it's ambiguous. However, that said I do now see where there is some confusion and I'm going to address it in a follow up comment to Mari-Lou's right after this one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I will make adjustments to my answer. Technically I see where some of the English "purists" are coming from on this one now. But in a technical environment (ray-tracer is a  mathematical program to calculate how light rays affect a scene - used to generate certain images & make enhancements) it's very common; and that's why I said no one would familiar in that environment would possibly mistake "implement a beautiful image" as his reference. That being said I do see that it could confuse some. I'll update it and add a better one to the comments as well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Once I finished the project, I found that implementing a ray-tracer is a lot more challenging than generating a beautiful image", is probably a syntactically better option (particularly for anyone not familiar with computer science or ray-tracing).

Comment: @Kace36 - I think he was saying the opposite:  Implementing a ray-tracer is much easier than actually creating  a beautiful image using one.

Comment: @Jim Very good point. I think that was his intention now that I see his marked answer for Roger. It was the bungled construction of the sentence and the usage of "implementing a beautiful image" that messed things up. He got his noun and verb objects completely turned around is what happened I think. At any rate +1 on the comment. I'll probably update my answer.